# How do I get a sequence of Views to show / hide / change in android studio?

Tags: java, android-studio, imageview, android-imageview

When I press a button / when the activity starts, I want a sequence (4-9 long - randomly chosen) of image-Views to appear and disappear, so that only one at a time is showing. The goal of this is to highlight shapes in a sequence on a randomly generated grid.
The problem is, the grid never updates until the entire sequence is completed, and the image-views for highlighting never show up. I have tried it on a real device and not just the emulator and I have the same problem.
Here is my code for it:

```
public void startSequence(){
    ImageView OverPos0 = findViewById(R.id.overPos0);
    ImageView OverPos1 = findViewById(R.id.overPos1);
    ImageView OverPos2 = findViewById(R.id.overPos2);
    ImageView OverPos3 = findViewById(R.id.overPos3);
    ImageView OverPos4 = findViewById(R.id.overPos4);
    ImageView OverPos5 = findViewById(R.id.overPos5);
    ImageView OverPos6 = findViewById(R.id.overPos6);
    ImageView OverPos7 = findViewById(R.id.overPos7);
    ImageView OverPos8 = findViewById(R.id.overPos8);
    ImageView OverPoss[] = {OverPos0,OverPos1,OverPos2,OverPos3,OverPos4,OverPos5,OverPos6,OverPos7,OverPos8};

    Random random = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
    Pass = "";
    String nums = "12345";
    int position = 1000;
    int passLength = random.nextInt(5)+4;
    System.out.println("Pass length = "+ passLength);
    for (int i = 0; i < passLength;i++){
        Pass = Pass + String.valueOf(nums.charAt(random.nextInt(nums.length())));
    }
    int currentPos = random.nextInt(9);
    while (Nodes[currentPos].shape != Integer.parseInt(Pass.substring(0,1))){
        currentPos = random.nextInt(9);
        System.out.println("currentPos = "+currentPos+", Nodes[currentPos].shape = "+Nodes[currentPos].shape+", Pass[0] = "+Integer.parseInt(Pass.substring(0,1)));
    }
    //OverPoss[currentPos].setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    OverPoss[currentPos].animate().alpha(1f).setDuration(100);
    position = currentPos;
    for (int x = 0; x < passLength; x++){
        try {
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        randomiseShapes(position);
        hidePoss();
        switch (Pass.charAt(x)){
            case '1':
                while (Nodes[currentPos].shape != 1 || position == currentPos){
                    currentPos = random.nextInt(5);
                    currentPos +=4;
                    for (int y = 0; y < Nodes[position].canSee.length; y++){
                        if (currentPos == Nodes[position].canSee[y]){
                            y = Nodes[position].canSee.length;
                        }
                    }

                System.out.println("currentPos = "+currentPos+", Nodes[currentPos].shape = "+Nodes[currentPos].shape+", Pass["+x+"] = "+Integer.parseInt(Pass.substring(0,1))+", Nodes[position].canSee = "+ Arrays.toString(canSees[position]));
                }
                //OverPoss[position].setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                OverPoss[position].animate().alpha(0f).setDuration(100);
                OverPoss[currentPos].animate().alpha(1f).setDuration(100);
                //OverPoss[currentPos].setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                position = currentPos;
                break;
            case '2':
                while (Nodes[currentPos].shape != 2 || position == currentPos){
                    currentPos = random.nextInt(9);
                    for (int y = 0; y < Nodes[position].canSee.length; y++){
                        if (currentPos == Nodes[position].canSee[y]){
                            y = Nodes[position].canSee.length;
                        }
                    }

                    System.out.println("currentPos = "+currentPos+", Nodes[currentPos].shape = "+Nodes[currentPos].shape+", Pass["+x+"] = "+Integer.parseInt(Pass.substring(0,1))+", Nodes[position].canSee = "+Arrays.toString(canSees[position]));
                }
                //OverPoss[position].setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                OverPoss[position].animate().alpha(0f).setDuration(100);
                OverPoss[currentPos].animate().alpha(1f).setDuration(100);
                //OverPoss[currentPos].setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                position = currentPos;
                break;
            case '3':
                while (Nodes[currentPos].shape != 3 || position == currentPos){
                    currentPos = random.nextInt(9);
                    for (int y = 0; y < Nodes[position].canSee.length; y++){
                        if (currentPos == Nodes[position].canSee[y]){
                            y = Nodes[position].canSee.length;
                        }
                    }

                    System.out.println("currentPos = "+currentPos+", Nodes[currentPos].shape = "+Nodes[currentPos].shape+", Pass["+x+"] = "+Integer.parseInt(Pass.substring(0,1))+", Nodes[position].canSee = "+Arrays.toString(canSees[position]));
                }
                //OverPoss[position].setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                OverPoss[position].animate().alpha(0f).setDuration(100);
                OverPoss[currentPos].animate().alpha(1f).setDuration(100);
                //OverPoss[currentPos].setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                position = currentPos;
                break;
            case '4':
                while (Nodes[currentPos].shape != 4 || position == currentPos){
                    currentPos = random.nextInt(9);
                    for (int y = 0; y < Nodes[position].canSee.length; y++){
                        if (currentPos == Nodes[position].canSee[y]){
                            y = Nodes[position].canSee.length;
                        }
                    }

                    System.out.println("currentPos = "+currentPos+", Nodes[currentPos].shape = "+Nodes[currentPos].shape+", Pass["+x+"] = "+Integer.parseInt(Pass.substring(0,1))+", Nodes[position].canSee = "+Arrays.toString(canSees[position]));
                }
                //OverPoss[position].setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                OverPoss[position].animate().alpha(0f).setDuration(100);
                OverPoss[currentPos].animate().alpha(1f).setDuration(100);
                //OverPoss[currentPos].setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                position = currentPos;
                break;
            case '5':
                while (Nodes[currentPos].shape != 5 || position == currentPos){
                    currentPos = random.nextInt(9);
                    for (int y = 0; y < Nodes[position].canSee.length; y++){
                        if (currentPos == Nodes[position].canSee[y]){
                            y = Nodes[position].canSee.length;
                        }
                    }

                    System.out.println("currentPos = "+currentPos+", Nodes[currentPos].shape = "+Nodes[currentPos].shape+", Pass["+x+"] = "+Integer.parseInt(Pass.substring(0,1))+", Nodes[position].canSee = "+Arrays.toString(canSees[position]));
                }
                //OverPoss[position].setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                OverPoss[position].animate().alpha(0f).setDuration(100);
                OverPoss[currentPos].animate().alpha(1f).setDuration(100);
                //OverPoss[currentPos].setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                position = currentPos;
                break;
        }
    }
    try {
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    //OverPoss[position].setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    OverPoss[position].animate().alpha(0f).setDuration(100);
    randomiseShapes(1000);
    entering = false;
}
```

Sorry for the bad asker etiquette but I am at my wits end trying to figure this out, as you can see I have tried using animations instead of setting the views to visible or invisible. Any help would be greatly appreciated and if I can provide any more information please let me know.

- Nodes = The grid points that have the shapes for the sequence\n
- OverPos = The circles that highlight the chosen shape
- Nodes.canSee = The positions of the other nodes than can be
  accessed in a straight line from this one
- Nodes.shape = numerical value for each of the 5    shapes they can be
  (1-5)